# Linking Tkinter label based on Entry value

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to make a Tkinter label that automatically updates to reflect changes in the text of an Entry field?  For example, if the Entry has the text "1", the label should say "T1", but if the user changes the text in entry to "x" then the label should say "Tx", without having to press a button.

Comment: Without having to press a button? I don't think so.

Comment: @AlexThornton: incorrect. This is easy to do in Tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley Damn, I was thinking of a `StringVar`, but I didn't know about `trace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The easiest way I can think of is using the `.trace` method of a `StringVar`, which calls a function if the value of the `StringVar()` changes. Here's an example:

```
def change_label(*args):
    label.config(text='') # clear label
    label.config(text='T' + var.get()) # set new label text

root = Tk()

var = StringVar() # make the StringVar()

label = Label(root)
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var) # set the textvariable to var

var.trace('w', change_label) # trace var to monitor for changes, calling function on change

label.pack()
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

More on `trace`: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm